# How to globally declare this Python list

Tags: python

```
import concurrent.futures
import urllib.request
import json

myurls = {}
for x in range(1, 15):
    for y in range(1, 87):

        strvar1 = "%s" % (x)
        strvar2 = "%s" % (y)

        with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_{}_{}.txt".format(x,y),"r") as f:
            myurls[x,y] = f.read().replace('\n', '')            
            print("myurls_" + str(strvar1) + "_" + str(strvar2) + "=", myurls[x,y])

            def myglob():
                global myurls


            URLS = [myurls2_1_1,myurls2_1_2,myurls2_1_3,myurls2_1_4,myurls2_1_5 ETC>>>ETC >>>]
```

The code below here works fine. The idea is:

1. Define multiple strings from multiple source .txt files into a dictionary.
2. Pass these multiple variables to the URLS = [] statement at the same time so that they may be processed in parallel using the concurrent.futures module for python.

Comment: def myglob():
   global myurls 

works syntax wise but the list of variables I then want to use i.e. myurls2_1_1, myurls2_1_2 etc are throwing up an error saying that they are not defined.

Comment: You don't need that. Trust me.

Comment: Agreed with @glglgl, after reading your comments it is obvious that you should open a new question with your actual problem, rather than problems with your attempt to solve the problem in a strange way. Or alternatively, edit and rewrite this question completely

Comment: my last couple of comments have disappeared and i am not sure what you mean @glglgl...what wont i need?

Comment: For some reasons why you don't need it see [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html).

Comment: @user3043997 Are you asking how to convert a dictionary into a list?

Comment: Why is the definition of `URLS` inside the `for y in ...` loop?

Comment: What's `f.read().replace('\n', '') ` supposed to do? Is there only one URL per file?

Comment: Why do you need `myurls[x,y]` at all? Can you not just do `URLS = []` in the beginning and then do `URLS.append(f.read().replace('\n',''))` in the loop? Because from how I interpret your code, that would have the exact same effect. But then I can't read your mind to figure out what you actually *want* to do

Comment: there is one URL per text file...the f.read().replace('\n', '') removes the line breaks that are present in the resolved variable once it is read in from the text file. when i was using a single example of a URL (so no dictionary defining multiple variables that resolve to URLS in the format myurls2_1_1) it worked fine.

Comment: The point of the dictionary is that there multiple text files with the naming convention C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_x_y.txt...I want to read each of these in and in turn pass them to a variable of the naming convention myurls2_1_1...once I have multiple of these defined I can submit them all at once to URLS=[]. I dont want to submit them one at a time as this loses the advantage of parallel submission.

Comment: I have also edited my original question as you suggested.

Comment: @user3043997 What parallel submission are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> ```
> def myglob():
>     global myurls
> ```
>
> works syntax wise but the list of variables I then want to use i.e. `myurls2_1_1`, `myurls2_1_2` etc are throwing up an error saying that they are not defined.

That is right. But you are quite close: just access them exactly the way you defined them: as `myurls[1,1]` or how you defined them.

Defining variables in a dynamic way is almost never the way to go; normally you can achieve that by any dict key or list index access.

As you now provided an example, I can exactly show how you'd do:

```
myurls = {}
for x in range(1, 15):
    for y in range(1, 87):

        strvar1 = "%s" % (x) # you can omit these.
        strvar2 = "%s" % (y)

        with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_{}_{}.txt".format(x,y),"r") as f: # This is NOT the right place to put an application-specific config file.
            myurls[x,y] = f.read().replace('\n', '')            
            print("myurls[%d,%d] = %s" % (x, y, myurls[x,y]))

            def myglob(): # this function is completely pointless.
                global myurls

# Construct your urls list only after you have everything that belongs in it, i. e. on the correct indentation level:
urls = [myurls[1,1], myurls[1,2], myurls[1,3], myurls[1,4], ...]
```

This would be one way to go. It looks very complicated and weird, this last, very long line.

But you can shorten it with a list comprehension:

```
urls = [myurls[x,y] for x in range(1, 15) for y in range(1, 87)]
```

But then, you might be asked: "Why not construct it on the way already?"

Well, here we go:

```
myurls = {}
urls = []
for x in range(1, 15):
    for y in range(1, 87):

        with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_{}_{}.txt".format(x,y), "r") as f:
            thisfile = f.read().replace('\n', '')
            myurls[x,y] = thisfile
            urls.append(thisfile)
            print("myurls[%d,%d] = %s" % (x, y, thisfile))
```

and there you are.

There is no need to put them all at once into the list, as this has nothing to do with parallelization, which only seems to come later.

All that counts is that you have the `urls` present at the start of the parallelization. If this happens at once or item by item does not matter.

Comment: myurls = {}
for x in range(1, 15):
    for y in range(1, 87):

        strvar1 = "%s" % (x)
        strvar2 = "%s" % (y)
            
        with open("C:\\Python33\\NASDAQ Stock Strings\\NASDAQ_Config_File_{}_{}.txt".format(x,y),"r") as f:
            myurls[x,y] = f.read().replace('\n', '')            
            #print("myurls2_" + str(strvar1) + "_" + str(strvar2) + "=", myurls[x,y])

            def myglob():
                global myurls
    
            URLS = [myurls[1,1]]

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\test2.py", line 295, in <module>
    mylen = (len(myurls2)) - 1
NameError: name 'myurls' is not defined

Comment: I'm still not quite there with something.

Comment: @user3043997 Dude, we can't be expected to guess what you're trying to do there, but it obviously doesn't have anything to do with your original question

Comment: @NiklasB. I have amended my question to include my full code.

Comment: @user3043997: You must be joking. Do you expect somebody to read through all this?

Comment: @NiklasB i appreciate your time but if you are not interesting in helping me can you please go away? i'm a SAS programmer who is really new to python and as a result I am asking questions that you might find a little bone headed and maybe I'm not asking them in the right way, but your attitude is really poor and you are coming across as impatient and superior. this forum isn't just for people who are highly proficient. if you find beginners lack of ability frustrating or offensive could i please suggest you dont comment on them as you will put people off the site. thanks.

Comment: @user3043997: Sorry, but if you think that this site appreciates you dumping almost 400 lines of code and let people figure out what's wrong, then you are most definitely mistaken. This is not just my personal opinion, it's all in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I posted a brief snippet of code which you weren't happy about, then I posted all of it which you also weren't happy about. You haven't contributed anything positive to this at all

Comment: @user3043997 You possibly want to provide a short code snippet that actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I'm asking once I have created a dictionary, how can I declare that globally so that I can pass all of the variables within it to a line of code that pre defines multiple URL strings at the same time to be processed later in the code in parallel. Can you help me with that?

Comment: In my above example you need only concern yourself up to the line URLS=[] everything else after that works ok.

Comment: Guys, keep calm. @user3043997, I have extended my answer so that it fits your code.

Comment: @glglgl Would give one more +1 if I could :)

Comment: @glglgl I worked out a solution in the end, but thanks for replying. It turned out I didn't need to make them global after all. I knew what I wanted and how I would do that in SAS but not how to explain it in Python terms. Also, it didn't occur to me that i needed to deindent the URLS = statement to remove it from the for loop logic above. I will remember this code though for when i do need to globally declare variables.

When i initially ran it only the last iteration was being processed.

Comment: @glglgl i would post my solution but with a rep less than 10 you cant post answers less than eight hours after your original question.